# Why QGIS3 is not running processing models and scripts in background?

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-processing, qgis-modeler

I have a problem with QGIS 3.6.0 on macos and QGIS3.2.3 on Windows7 with running processing scripts and models in background. According to [QGIS3 docs](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/processing/scripts.html#flags) they are run in background thread by default (if there is no [FlagNoThreading](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.4/core/QgsProcessingAlgorithm.html#qgis.core.QgsProcessingAlgorithm.FlagNoThreading) flag defined.

Unfortunately there is no "run in background" button on processing dialog (just "Run") and they are run in main GUI thread (or in other thread but blocking GUI anyway).

I couldn't find any QGIS configuration setting for this. What could be the reason for QGIS3 to run them in GUI-blocking mode?

Comment: Is your Windows7 OS 32 or 64 bit?

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to answer my own question because I just solved the issue myself.

The issue is only with models, not scripts and is caused by [this line in QGIS3 code](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/943c7d5d905d66b56f12cb4a0e9d5f3c9bbe54ae/src/core/processing/models/qgsprocessingmodelalgorithm.cpp#L96).

```
QgsProcessingAlgorithm::Flags QgsProcessingModelAlgorithm::flags() const
{
    // TODO - check child algorithms, if they all support threading, then the model supports threading...
    return QgsProcessingAlgorithm::flags() | QgsProcessingAlgorithm::FlagNoThreading;
}
```

It adds `FlagNoThreading` flag by default and in each and every case to the model-based algorithm. So every model runs in main GUI thread by default and you can't change that as a QGIS3 user.

**The solution is** to use "Export Model as Python algorithm ..." option, save the model as processing .py **script** and run it as a script. It runs in background just fine.